# How to display buttons as inline/block elements when one button is wrapped into a form?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, bootstrap-4

How to display two buttons as block elements on small screens as well as inline elements on larger screens, when one of the buttons is wrapped inside a form?

I have two buttons, one is only a local link, the other one is wrapped (by my colleague) inside a from. Now I'm getting problems when displaying the page on smaller screens. The button inside the form will not appear as a block element anymore.

Result should look like this:

**Small screen:**

|          button1          |

|          button2          |

---

**Large screen:**

| button1 | | button2 |

---

**My code so far**:

https://www.bootply.com/CETPAyWp2K

(resize screen width to see the effect)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update your styles to make the button take full space in mobile view.
Try using the following styles, that should work:

```
form { display: block; }

form button {
   width:100%;
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
    form {
        display: inline;
    }

    form button {
       width: auto;
    }
}
```

Comment: All of the given solutions work for me, thank you guys! I like this one the most, because it follows the direction I was going so far until I got stuck - AND it means the easiest implementation of all.

Comment: sorry... but better to use bootstrap 4 classes(`w-100`) they create for this reason(class and not css)

Comment: That's another way to solve it, yeah. But in my case I would have had to implement an extra div to each table where I wanted to have a line break. It's far easier to do it this way when you have a lot of data tables . Just MY opinion

Answer (score 1):

Use [w-100](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/sizing/) to  `button[type="submit"]`
 and in `media-query` of lg screen use:

```
@media (min-width: 992px) {
    form {
        display: inline;
    }
    button[type="submit"]{
  width: auto!important;
}
}
```

See fiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/m9n4dgw7/5/

```css
form { display: block; 

}


@media (min-width: 992px) {
    form {
        display: inline;
    }
    button[type="submit"]{
  width: auto!important;
}
}
```

```html
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Name</th>
      <th scope="col" class="text-right">Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="content_name">Samplecol 1</td>
      
      <td class="text-right">
        <a class="btn btn-warning btn-sm btn-edit d-block d-lg-inline mb-1 mb-lg-0" href="#">Edit</a>
        <form action="http://localhost:10777/Delete/3aac236e" method="post">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm w-100 d-block d-lg-inline mb-1 mb-lg-0">Delete</button>
        </form>
      </td>
      
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="content_name">Samplecol 2</td>
      
      <td class="text-right">
        <a class="btn btn-warning btn-sm btn-edit d-block d-lg-inline mb-1 mb-lg-0" href="#">Edit</a>
        <form action="http://localhost:10777/Delete/d81de31b" method="post">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm w-100 d-block d-lg-inline mb-1 mb-lg-0">Delete</button>                         
        </form>
      </td>
      
    </tr>                
    
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: that what you mean?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Bootstrap and his grid to do responsive buttons.

For example you can use it as follow :

```
<td class="text-right">
    <a class="btn btn-warning btn-sm col-md-3 col-sm-12 mb-1 mb-lg-0" href="#">Edit</a>
    <form action="http://localhost:10777/Delete/3aac236e" method="post">
        <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm d-block d-lg-inline col-md-3 col-sm-12 mb-1 mb-lg-0" type="submit">Delete</button>
    </form>
</td>
```

In this example buttons use full width on small devices and 1/4 width on other devices.